# read splunk jsonArray with spath

Tags: arrays, json, splunk

Here is my set:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="[[\"A\",\"AA\"],[\"B\",\"BB\"],[\"C\",\"CC\"]]"
|spath  path={}{} output=data
```

I would like to have 3 distinct tuple the A together and B together and C together,
but i have all in one line with my request.

I can do something like

```
|spath  path={0}{} output=data0
|spath  path={1}{} output=data1
|spath  path={2}{} output=data2
```

but i'm looking for something more dynamic :)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data doesn't consist of any other JSON, you can use regular expressions to extract each entry and process it that way. Check this example.

```
| makeresults count=5
| eval random=random()
| eval _raw="[[\"A\",\"AA\"],[\"B\",\"BB\"],[\"C\",\"CC\"]]"
| rex max_match=0 field=_raw "(?<d>\[[^\[\]]+\])"
| mvexpand d
| streamstats count by random
| eval data_{count}=d
| fields _time, data_*, random
| stats values(_time) as _time, values(*) AS * by random
| fields - random
```

I added some extra complexity for the LOLs. The `streamstats` is used to get an incremental counter that is then used to create some new column names in the order of `data_0`, `data_1`, etc... A random number is generated at the start and included with the event, so you can join up all the split events at the end.